# How to detect Facebook oauth window closed action from user

Tags: facebook, oauth

I am trying to figure if there is any way to notify the parent page when user either closes or clicks on cancel button on Facebook permissions window during oauth flow. Its the window where user authorizes an app. The window with url: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?api_key=..... and with "Login with Facebook" and "Cancel" buttons. What I am trying to accomplish is-- If user cancels or closes the oauth permissions window, I would like to open Facebook simple sharing window where they can post status without authorizing the app.

I am using JS SDK for Facebook connect.

Comment: How are you doing this? Client side (javascript) or server side? Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: @NitzanTomer I am using Facebook JS SDK for this.

Answer (score 3):

This code is taken from the [documentation for the FB.login method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/):

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
```

As you can see, the `if (response.authResponse)` part checks rather the login process was finished successfully, that is, the user allowed the application and he is logged in to facebook.

If the user clicked "cancel" or closed the popup then there won't a `authResponse` parameter in the response.

Answer (score 2):

Observe the url as user cancel the authorization the oauth url changes, it will now contain number of fields to describe user action

```
YOUR_REDIRECT_URI?
    error_reason=user_denied
   &error=access_denied
   &error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.
   &state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE
```

This will be the value after user cancel the authentication

```
error_reason=user_denied
&error=access_denied
&error_description=The user denied your request
```

After user cancel's the authentication dialog page will be redirected to the parent page where you can check these error parameters.

Comment: I am using JS SDK provided by Facebook for Facebook Connect. With that, page doesnt really redirect anywhere if user clicks on "cancel". Also, user can just close the window instead of clicking on "cancel".

Comment: Yes there are two ways for that, if you are redirecting user to authentication page this method will work, if you are opening an authentication dialog above answer will work, user always has option to close the window you will check this by closing event but not with facebook sdk.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I'm authorizing user and also asking user to give me permission to Post on their wall but it doesn't return any error if user denies that request but accepts login request.

I hope my question makes sense.